# Magento2 PayPal Payflow Pro not redirected to success page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, paypal-payflow-pro

In my magento2 website the PayPal Payflow Pro not redirected to success page like after clicking on place order button the order successfully placed in admin and payment also processed but in checkout the loader keep loading and not redirected to checkout success page.

its only happen sometime not always and I have also checked this magento2 bug link 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7159

and above link's solution [loader issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e2ef171b414469f4c4b58c854aeb4b36e81c978a) code already updated on my website.
and I have checked the log data also and not any error related to payment gateway and payment log also showing Ok.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with Payflow was the store switcher, caused the page to hang and never return. It never did any of the order steps, just hung.

This is where the payflow returns to, but it has no store designation, that was that was what caused the problem

paypal/transparent/redirect/

adding paypal/* to the store switcher exclude solved it for me, hope it can help others.